# Using dropdown selection with Plotly Julia

Tags: julia, plotly, interactive, plots.jl

Using Plotly in Julia, I would like to filter the plot data based on the selection event for a dropdown as shown in the example for the similiar case with [Plotly in Python](https://plot.ly/python/selection-events/#populate-a-table-using-a-plotly-mouse-selection-event) that I reproduce here:

[image]

I went through the [PlotlyJS.jl](http://spencerlyon.com/PlotlyJS.jl/) documentation but could not find how to do it. Is filtering based on dropdown selections currently not supported in Plotly for Julia or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Interact.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGizmos/Interact.jl) and [Plots.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/) for this

```
using Interact, Plots
some_dataset  = rand( 10, 2)
other_dataset = rand( 10, 2)
datasets=Dict(:some  => some_dataset,
              :other => other_dataset)
@manipulate for dataset = [:some, :other]
    scatter(datasets[dataset])
end
```

Do mind that this will display a multiple-choice widget that's not a drop-down menu, but serves the same purpose. Check the Interact docs for precise information on how to use a drop-down instead.

Comment: Works great! For this to work with Juno, I had to use display(scatter(datasets[dataset]))